# How to convert directory structure to array of urls

Tags: php, arrays, directory-structure

I want to convert my directory structure to array format with file urls.
Here is my directory structure.

```
public
  |-product_001
      |-documents
      |   |- doc_001.txt
      |   |- doc_002.txt
      |   |- doc_003.txt
      |
      |-gallery
          |- img_001.png
          |- img_002.png
          |- img_003.png
```

And this is what i want:

```
array(
  'product_001' =>array(
      'documents' =>array(
         0 => "public/product_001/documents/doc_001.txt",
         1 => "public/product_001/documents/doc_002.txt",
         2 => "public/product_001/documents/doc_003.txt"
      )
      'gallery' =>array(
         0 => "public/product_001/gallery/img_001.png",
         1 => "public/product_001/gallery/img_002.png",
         2 => "public/product_001/gallery/img_003.png"
      )
  )
)
```

Here is function:

```
function dirToArray($dir,$url) {

    $result = array();

    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {

        if (!in_array($value, array(".", ".."))) {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) {
                $url.=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value;
                $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value,$url);
            } else {
                $result[] = $url.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Here is output i got till now:

```
Array
(
    [product_001] => Array
        (
            [documents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => public/product_001/documents/doc_001.txt
                    [1] => public/product_001/documents/doc_002.txt
                    [2] => public/product_001/documents/doc_003.txt
                )

            [gallery] => Array
                (
               [0] => public/product_001/documents/gallery/img_001.png
               [1] => public/product_001/documents/gallery/img_002.png
               [2] => public/product_001/documents/gallery/img_003.png
                )

        )

)
```

Can any one help me to achieve this?
Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, i have tried i'll post what i achieved

Comment: problem is with gallery file url. Document is inserted before gallery

Comment: Do i need to post my code as well?

Comment: @Maverick It would be helpful

Comment: And what's the difference between what you want and what you have now?

Comment: u_mulder : see gallery image carefully

Comment: His problem is `public/product_001/documents/gallery/img_003.png` should be `public/product_001/gallery/img_003.png`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308673/php-flatten-array-with-multiple-leaf-nodes/12309032#12309032

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be even easier.
Usually if you have a recursion you do not need state.
So just get read of yours $url and clean up  code no need to do concatenations multiple times.

As per `Ryan Vincents'` comment added dynamic separators.

As per `Mavericks'` comment added root parameter.

```
<?php

function dirToArray($dir, $separator = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $root = '') {

    $result = array();
    if ($root === '') {
        $root = $dir;
    }

    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {

        if (!in_array($value, array(".", ".."))) {
            $current = $dir . $separator . $value;

            if (is_dir($current)) {
                $result[$value] = dirToArray($current, $separator, $root);
            } else {
                $result[] = str_replace($root, '',$current);
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: @RyanVincent True that, Was just going of code provided. Not  an issue on Linux  :).

Comment: Just fixed SEPARATOR bug

Comment: We are close but its giving me path from root directory. /var/www/html/mobileApp/public/product_001/documents/doc_001.txt

Comment: for web service i  want path like this test.com/public/product_001/documents/doc_001.txt

Comment: thats why i was passing $url variable to function. any quick edit for that?

Comment: @Maverick Fixed added root parameter do not pass it if your root is folder you iterate over.